# Adjective meaning "greater than one"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

If you want to describe a number that is greater than zero, you would use *positive*. Is there a similar term for numbers (not necessarily integers) that are greater than one? I.e., this term would be to multiplication as *positive* is to addition.

For example, I have a box in a figure that says "Antecedent: Factor Greater Than One", but that's a bigger name than most of the antecedents (or consequents) in my figures, so I'd really like it to say something like "Antecedent: Superpositive Factor" where "Superpositive" is a word I made up right now that I hope will never have the meaning I'm attributing to it here.

Plural has been suggested, and that's a really good answer for discrete quantities (such as the number of dogs), but in my particular case the number in question is continuous (a multiplicative factor).

Per request, here are other Antecedent/Consequent names I've used (after the "Antecedent:" or "Consequent:" bit): "Nonnegative Divisor", "Acceptable Error", "In Between Result", "Min Less Than Max" (which is equally as wordy), and "Applies Brake When At Rest" (which is even more wordy). So far, I've eschewed using actual math symbols (such as "> 1"), but I don't really have a solid reason for doing so.

Comment: Plural numbers perhaps?

Comment: Give an example of how you'd use this.

Comment: @HotLicks, added an example to the question

Comment: this may sound stupid, but why don't you just write "Antecedent: Factor > 1"? sometimes simpler is better...

Comment: @SamuelVimes, not stupid, and better than "Antecedent: Factor Greater Than One", but not *quite* as good as I'm hoping for.

Comment: For context it would be useful to see how you labelled the other antecedents. Otherwise we can't judge what you are aiming for.

Comment: "Plurality" is sometimes used to mean "more than one" ("a plurality of potatoes"), but I've never heard "plural" used in a similar sense.  And either word would seem weird in your context.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK, added that to the question

Comment: What's wrong with 'multiple'?  I know in theory zero and one could be multiples, but common usage as well as the OED ("Having or involving several parts, elements, or members") suggests there would be more than one.  If too vague, then 'multiple >1'.

Comment: *productive*?   Though if the quantity which is the mathematical product here is anything more specific, there are likely better terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can use "Antecedent:*[plural number](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/plural)*", although I think that it would be fine if you just write "Antecedent:Factor > 1"

Comment: Plural is good in some situations, but I will clarify my answer to include that I'm looking for an answer that works with uncountable quantities.

Comment: Never heard about plural numbers.

Comment: Accepting in lieu of a better answer, in that while this doesn't exactly suit my needs, it's a good answer for situations involving countable quantities.